# Regex not separating n't (not)

Tags: regex

I am trying to write a complex regex for a large corpus. However, due to many ORs, I am not able to capture the "not" in *weren't don't wasn't didn't shouln't doesn't*

I would like it to match **base verb** and **n't** separately: E.g. **were** and **n't**

I have added it in the first line on: https://www.regexpal.com/?fam=106183 with the regex.

Any clue why it is not picking despite it being present in the expression on first order: [a-z]{1}'\w

**Edit:**
The regex is long because it is part of a large corpus. My problem is that the n't is not getting separated out, even though I placed in first order of preference for OR.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Your regex is always consuming the `n` before it begins matching the `'t`.  You probably need a lookahead somewhere to make sure you *don't* match an `n` where a `'t` follows

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Trying to parse natural language perfectly with a regular expression is never going to be "perfect". Language contains too many quirks and exceptions.

However, with that said, trying to cover all scenarios explicitly like you have done ("a 2 letter lower case word", "a 4 letter capitalised word", "a word with a multiple of 3 letters" (??!), ... is a doomed approach.

Keep the pattern as simple as you possibly can, and only add exceptions if you really need to.

Here's a basic approach:

```
/n't|\b\w+(?!'t)/
```

This is matching `"n't"`, or 'any word, excluding the last letter if it's proceeded by `"'t"`'.

You may wish to build upon that slightly, but it solved the use case you've provided:

[**Demo**](https://regex101.com/r/bxzWAL/1)

---

In order to understand why your original pattern doesn't work, let's consider a **Minimal**, Complete, Verifiable Example:

Cutting your pattern down to:

```
/[a-z]?'[a-z]{1,}|[\w-]+/
```

Consider how it matches the string:

```
"weren't"
```

- First, the characters `weren` are matched by the `[\w-]+` portion of the pattern.
- Then, the `'t` characters are matched by the `[a-z]?'[a-z]{1,}` portion of the pattern.

Fundamentally, having the greedy `[\w-]+` section in this pattern will mean it cannot work. This will always match up-to-and-including the `"n"` in `"n't"`, which means the overall match fails for non-3-letter words.

Comment: Thanks. But somehow I need help to find out why the initial pattern in my regex works as standalone to pick "n't" and not with the rest, despite it being first in the order of multiple ORs...

Comment: @feijao See my edit. It's caused by the sequence of matches, not one standalone match.